# Add Elements to ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of `ArrayList`. How can I add an element to the list in specific position?

Example:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>=new ArrayList<>(list,list2,.....,listn);
```

I want to add an element to list2 for example.

Comment: Please read the Java doc for Array List. You would get to know yourself

Comment: `list.get(index1).add(value);`, where `index1` is an index from [0 - N - 1].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would get the second element and add to it: -

```
list.get(1).add(myString);
```

Remember it's 0 based though.

Answer (score 3):

You need to get from your outer ArrayList your desired inner ArrayList first like

```
outerList.get(1); //this will return list2
```

then you can add to that inner arrayList some values like

```
outerList.get(1).add("your value"); //this will add element to list2
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you named your list 'list':

```
list.get(1).add("x");
```

Where x is whatever you want to add to the second list.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have `list2`, it's easy. You do :

```
list2.add("Moon");
```

If you only have the big list, which we shall call `bigList`, you do :

```
bigList.get(1).add("Moon");
```

Indexes in Java start at 0.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myList=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list1=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list2=new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> list3=new ArrayList<>();
    list1.add("a") ; // add elements for list1

    list2.add("b");  // add elements for list2

    list3.add("c");  // add elements for list3

    myList.add(list1); // add elements for myList
    myList.add(list2);
    myList.add(list3);


    //Now I want to add new value for list2
    myList.get(1).add("bb");     // indexes start with zero same as Arrays
```